# How to delete a specific string entry out of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I am trying to delete string out of array but the string is staying there. Any suggestions?

```
 $scope.removeFavorites = function (word) {
    debugger;
    // retrieve it (Or create a blank array if there isn't any info saved yet),
    var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoritesInfo')) || [];

    for (var i = favorites.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (favorites[i] === word {
        favorites.splice(i, 1); 
        console.log(favorites[i]);
      }
    }
    //favorites.pop();
    // localStorage.setItem('favoritesInfo', JSON.stringify(favorites));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('favoritesInfo'));
  }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code - a missing `)` in the `if` line

Comment: `if (favorites[i] === word {` there is a typo missing closing if condition `)`???

Comment: Your code works fine when it doesnt have the syntax error: https://jsfiddle.net/6hsz4qs0/

Comment: The syntax is just an accident on this post. I will that

Comment: Weird it works for Jamiec let me try just == instead of ===

Comment: So I can reach a debugger inside of the condition. For some reason the variable is persisting

Comment: smh....I had a line commented out...    // localStorage.setItem('favoritesInfo', JSON.stringify(favorites));

Comment: Can I take down this post?

Comment: BTW you can shorten your `for` loop to this: `favorites = favorites.filter(w => (w !== word))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code the splicing is being done to favorites array which gets the values from the localstorage

```
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoritesInfo')) || [];
```

so the value is removed in favorites array but not in the localstorage.

`localStorage.getItem('favoritesInfo')` still contains the complete set of values.

You have two solutions.

1. Use the favorites array which is your filtered set of list where
   ever needed.
2. Update the local storage with the favorites array to
       keep both in sync.